# adding columns to datatable datatype nvarchar

Tags: c#, database

I declared a new dataset.
Then added a datatable to it using the following command

```
DataTable newtable = ds.Tables.Add("returnresult");
```

now am trying to include two columns in this datatable with datatype "nvarchar".
But the usual command for this does not accept nvarchar as a datatype

```
 newtable.Columns.Add("UniqueID",typeof());
```

using this command does not show nvarchar in the datatypes.
is there any other command to get nvarchar as the datatype for columns?

Comment: Use `string` instead.

Comment: but am using it for getting the results from stored procedure.so i cant change it to string,for the columns data type must remain same

Comment: okay!i didnot know that string in .net is equivalent to nvarchar in database.thanks:)

Answer (score 8):

The type `nvarchar` is a database type, the `DataTable` is an in-memory objectThe type `nvarchar`/`varchar` is `string` which is the default type if you add a column.

So this creates and adds a `DataColumn` of type `string` to the table:

```
newtable.Columns.Add("UniqueID");  // or:
newtable.Columns.Add("UniqueID", typeof(string));
```

If you want to specify the maximum length of a text column use it's [`MaxLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.maxlength.aspx) property.

But if you fill a `DataTable` from database you should use  [`DataAdapter.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx) which automaticially infers the type and length from the database type.

The [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx) property supports the following base .NET Framework data types:

```
Boolean
Byte
Char
DateTime
Decimal
Double
Guid
Int16
Int32
Int64
SByte
Single
String
TimeSpan
UInt16
UInt32
UInt64
Byte[]
```

Comment: but what about the length?

Comment: i used nvarchar(20) n nvarchar(max).if i use string how will i define the length

Comment: @rahulvaid: Use the `MaxLength` property. I have edited my answer accordingly. But if you fill a DataTable from database you should use a `DataAdapter` which automaticially infers the type and length from the database type.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, `string` is the equivalent of `NVARCHAR(Any Length)`, `VARCHAR(Any Length)`, etc...

Try: `newtable.Columns.Add("UniqueID",typeof(string));`

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataTable newtable = ds.Tables.Add("returnresult");
        DataColumn newcolumn = newtable.Columns.Add("UniqueID", typeof(string));
        //newcolumn.MaxLength = n;   // nchar(n)
        newcolumn.MaxLength = 536.870.912; //nvarchar(max)  Variable-length Unicode data. Max 536.870.912 chars.
```

Comment: i used nvarchar(max),what should i use for max length?

Comment: I think that is probably unnecessary to specify MaxLength in this case.